# Node.js ElastiSearch client. How to use filter_path parameter with _msearch method

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I use https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js ElasticSearch client in my application.
I want use Multi Search API and reduce response with *filter_path* parameter.
In Kibana request looks like:

```
POST _msearch?filter_path=responses.hits.total
{ "index": "first_index" }
{"query": {"term": {"status": 1}} }
{ "index": "second_index" }
{"query": {"term": {"status": 1}} }
```

Response:

```
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "hits": {
        "total": 1935
      }
    },
    {
      "hits": {
        "total": 1212
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I can't find right place where should be this *filter_path* parameter in *client.msearch* method. Something like:

```
client.msearch({
    body: [
        { "index": "first_index" },
        { "q": 'filter_path=responses.hits.total' },
        {"query": {"term": {"status": 1}} },
        { "index": "second_index" },
        { "q": 'filter_path=responses.hits.total' },
        {"query": {"term": {"status": 1}} }
    ]
})
```

does't work.
How can I send this request with Node.js ElasticSearch Client?

Answer (score 4):

filterPath key should be given at the same level with `body`.

```
client.msearch({
    body: [
        { "index": "first_index" },
        {"query": {"term": {"status": 1}} },
        { "index": "second_index" },
        { "q": 'filter_path=responses.hits.total' },
        {"query": {"term": {"status": 1}} }
    ],
    filterPath: "responses.hits.total"
})
```

msearch function takes a parameter type of MSearchParams.

```
msearch<T>(params: MSearchParams): Promise<MSearchResponse<T>>;
```

I recommend you to install the [elasticsearch type definition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/elasticsearch) and so you can see the type hierarchy

```
export interface MSearchParams extends GenericParams {
    search_type?: "query_then_fetch" | "query_and_fetch" | "dfs_query_then_fetch" | "dfs_query_and_fetch";
    maxConcurrentSearches?: number;
    index?: NameList;
    type?: NameList;
}

export interface GenericParams {
    requestTimeout?: number;
    maxRetries?: number;
    method?: string;
    body?: any;
    ignore?: number | number[];
    filterPath?: string | string[];
}
```